# Is it possible to reconfigure web server after phpmyadmin installation?

Tags: apache2, configuration, phpmyadmin

So, I've installed phpmyadmin without selecting a webserver (I've just forgot to tap [space] to select), and I need to repair this, but when I reinstall phpmyadmin, it doesn't ask me for a web server after that. So, is it possible? How do I do this? (I need to use Apache2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found on google at page 3 how to see my actual phpmyadmin conf and then reconfigure it:

See current config:

```
sudo debconf-show phpmyadmin
```

And then, reconfigure it:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

I didn't need to reconfigure my dbs, so I've hit no and then web server selection has appeared to be reconfigured.